# dynamic value for structure array?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct What_if

{

    char price[2];
} what_if ;

 what_if  *what_if_var;

int main(int argc,int argv[])

{
 int m= argv[1];

what_if_var[m]='\0'; 

format_input_records();

getch();

return 0;

}

int format_input_records()

{

        strcpy(what_if_var[0].price,"sss") ;

        printf("\ntrans_Indicator     ==== : : %s",what_if_var[0].price);

return 0;

}
```

here i need dynamic value for structure array size ?how can i achieve this plz help me?

Comment: Are you trying to take input as a command line param and use that as the size of the array of structs you create?

Comment: You lack basic understanding of the language. The best help you can get is reading an introductory C book.

Comment: s chad..am  trying to take input as a command line param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a problem in that I don't think you understand what a pointer is:

```
what_if  *what_if_var;
...
what_if_var[m]='\0';
```

You created a pointer to a `What_if` struct, never allocate anything, then try and use it (and as an array of them)

You also don't have the correct signature for `main()`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

**As noted by a direct comment to your question, this is an indication that you really don't understand the basics of the language, and an introductory book is in order.**

That being said, what you need is an array of your structs the size of which is passed in via `argv` (after converting it from char* to int), and inside the struct you'd need to have a `char *` pointer. For each thing you want to store, you will need to `malloc()` or use `strdup()` then assign it to the pointer in your struct.

Comment: i need array of structure size as 1000 like what_if_var[1000], this 1000 i will get it from command line param

Comment: thanks brain, what_if_var=(what_if*)malloc((atoi(argv[1]))*(sizeof(what_if*)); i done like this...

Answer (score 0):

You could define :

```
typedef struct What_if


     char *price;
} what_if;
```

in your struct.
The initialize it when you know the exact size of chars to be stored:

```
struct what_if w;
w.price = malloc (sizeof(char) * NEEDED_CHAR);
```

Comment: @Jesn Gusdedt: what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate `what_if_var` with a call to `malloc()` before you can assign to it. I would also advise you to avoid using a global variable. Instead make `what_if_var` local.